# call aspx.cs method from asp.net web service c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am creating a web app in asp.net, I am using javascript to some extend, here the problem arrives, in one of the scenerio, I am calling web service from `$.Ajax`

and after the execution of web service which looks like the following

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
{
     //here I want to hit a method which is located in aspx.cs page to bind my grid;
}
```

how can I execute a method which is located in aspx.cs page to bind my grid from my webmethod in webservice

Comment: You cannot call aspx.cs method from Webmethod, what you should do is refactor your code and move that method into some Business layer which can be called both from your aspx page and WebMethod. Cheers!!

Comment: That won't help rebind the grid.

Comment: Do a search for 'how to bind a grid from javascript'; I'm pretty sure there are examples here. (Assuming that's all you need to do.)